# Where should questions about software development tools go?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, superuser, scope

I'm thinking about source revision control systems, development process, testing automation, etc. Are these appropriate for Stack Overflow, or do they fall under Super User's scope?

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers": 100% SO, 0% SU.

Comment: @VonC: It's amazing how many people hit 3k rep, promptly forget the FAQ, and start trying to close all the VCS and editor questions, isn't it?

Comment: @Jefromi: it is indeed. I didn't think there was any "grey area" regarding VCS tool, but what do I know ;) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are objective questions, by all means post them on SO. From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), you can post questions about:

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession