# Are questions about IDEs on topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

Would questions about Visual Studio or Netbeans that are not directly related to writing code be off topic on SO?

The question I have in mind would be something along the lines of: Must know Visual Studio hot keys? (Marked as a Community Wiki of course)

I ask this with the intention of how to save time and focus on the code instead of hunting and pecking through the Visual Studio interface to find something to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should questions about software development tools go?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61720/where-should-questions-about-software-development-tools-go)

Comment: FWIW the term "hunting and pecking" is usually reserved for a typing behavior, not searching through GUI menus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IDEs are absolutely *on* topic. From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), you can post questions about:

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession

It's worth noting, however, that all the usual rules about subjective/poll questions still apply.

Comment: Are questions about online IDEs considered on-topic as well, or do these questions belong on webapps.stackexchange.com (which is for discussion of web applications)?

Answer (score 2):

In general IDEs are on topic.  However, your particular question has already been asked.

[Favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts)