# Where should I ask questions related to WinDbg?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should questions about software development tools go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61720/where-should-questions-about-software-development-tools-go)

I have a question about WinDbg's output and I am not too sure where to ask the question. I have taken a guess and gone for Super User, but I wanted to check as it is indirectly related to programming — I am debugging a certain exception caused by programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow has a history of accepting questions about Eclipse, NetBeans, &c. so I would think they'd be okay with a question about a debugger like WinDbg. Super User tends to be more for general issues of system setup. The question might be moved automatically if enough SU users think it belongs on SO.

EDIT:
Assuming that [this](https://superuser.com/questions/198614/what-is-unloaded-type-in-windbg) is the question you're asking about, I would lean towards SO. But I think the existing system for sorting such things out will take care of it for you.

Comment: I have migrated the question.

Comment: Cheers for migrating this! :-)

Comment: The system works! (And there was much rejoicing, &c.)