# questions about development tools

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should questions about software development tools go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61720/where-should-questions-about-software-development-tools-go)

Are questions about not actual code, but usage of development tools considered appropriate on SO? For example, every day there appear questions about [VCS usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git). I think, the closest alternative, SU is worse place for them than SO.

Should such questions be considered offtopic on SO with reason "no code"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) says (emphasis mine):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in
>   them, but if your question generally
>   covers ...
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to
>   ask your question!

I would think that version control systems and (other tools used by developers) certainly fall under the third category, so they should be considered **on-topic**.